# How can I make the program go to the input?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Write a program that asks the user to put the password, first name, last name, and id. If any of that is invalid, program to continuously ask to provide the valid input. Here are the rules:

- Password has to be at least 7 characters, must contain at least one uppercase letter, at least one lowercase letter, and at least 1 digit
- First name and last name must contain only letters
- ID must contain only digits

After you have input everything validly print them on the screen. As the password is sensitive info print only the first three characters and for the rest of the length, print '*'

```
password = 'Pass1234'
first_name = 'John'
last_name = 'Smith'
ID = '1234'
    
p = input('Input your password: ')
    
if (len(p)<6):
    print('Invalid password. Must be at least 6 characters')
    p = input('Input your password: ')

elif not p.islower():
    print('Invalid password. Must have at least 1 lowercase character')
elif not p.isupper():
    print('Invalid password. Must have at least 1 uppercase character')

if p == password:
    print('Well done! This is a valid password')

password_list = list(password)
password_list[3] = '*'
password_list[4] = '*'
password_list[5] = '*'
password_list[6] = '*'
password_list[7] = '*'
edited_password = ''.join(password_list)


fn = input('Please enter your first name: ')
ln = input('Please enter your last name: ')

for f in fn:
    if f.isdigit():
        print('Invalid Name! Name should only contain letters')
        fn = input('Please enter your first name: ')
for l in ln:
    if l.isdigit():
        print('Invalid Name! Name should only contain letters')
        ln = input('Please enter your last name: ')
if fn == first_name or 'john' and ln == last_name or 'smith':
    print('Well done! This is a valid name')


I = input('Please enter your ID: ')

if I.isupper():
    print('Invalid ID! ID should only contain numbers')
    I = input('Please enter your ID: ')
elif I.islower():
    print('Invalid ID! ID should only contain numbers')
    I = input('Please enter your ID: ')
elif I == ID:
    ('Well done! This is a valid ID')

print('Name:', first_name, last_name)
print('ID:', ID)
print('Password:', edited_password)
```

Output:

```
Input your password: Pass1234
Invalid password. Must have at least 1 lowercase character
Well done! This is a valid password
Please enter your first name: John
Please enter your last name: Smith
Well done! This is a valid name
Please enter your ID: 1234
Name: John Smith
ID: 1234
Password: Pas*****
```

How can I fix my program where it doesn't print the lowercase error message?

Comment: This begs for a link to [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this. The problem you had is you were checking to see if your entire password was lowercase instead of if at least 1 character was.

Of course you'll probably want to change your input variable from "p" to "password" instead of hard coding it at the top of the page.

```
p = input("Input your password: ")
upper = 0
lower = 0 
number = 0
while True:
    for x in p:
        if x.isupper()==True:
            upper+=1
        elif x.islower()==True:
            lower+=1
        elif x.isalpha()==False:
            number+=1
    if len(p) < 7 or upper <= 0 or lower <= 0 or number <= 0:
        print ('password not complex enough')
        p = input('please enter password again ')
        upper = 0
        lower = 0
        number = 0
    else:
        break
```